# Question regarding JavaScript multiplication table

Tags: javascript, multiplication

I am trying to build a multiplication table  and display the results, but need to put the x in the top left corner, for some reason it is showing up on the bottom right, what am I doing wrong?

```js
document.write("<table><tbody>");
var blank = "x";
var cols = 0;
var rows = 0;
// ca
for (let rows = 0; rows <= 10; rows++) {
    document.write('<tr>');
    for (let cols = 0; cols <= 10; cols++)
        document.write('<td>' + rows + ',' + cols + '</td>')
}

if (rows === 0 && cols === 0) {
    document.write('<td>' + blank + '</td>')
}
```

Comment: Your `if` is in a spot where the variable `cols` is out of scope (doesn't exist).  Did you mean to put it inside the inner loop?

Comment: @James - Actually, it can be -- because it's not the same `cols` as in the loop (there's a `var cols = 0;` at the top). @​Tyro - I **strongly** recommend you don't redeclare variables in a narrower scope like that, it can be very confusing to read.

Comment: You are redifining `rows` and `cols` inside your for loops.

Comment: In your own code you can, of course, use any bracing and indentation style you like. But when asking other people for help, please use any of the standard styles, and be consistent. (And even in your own code, I really, really wouldn't do that thing where the `{` of a block is immediately followed by the first statement without any kind of break, and similarly the closing `}` of the block. Make blocks obvious and clearly set out.) I've fixed it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What am I doing wrong?" <strike>A lot</strike>.

You should think about what you are trying to do first, before going at it.

Your html table is ill-formed, you don't even close the `<tr>` tags.

```
for (let row = 0; row <= 10; row++) {
    document.write('<tr>');
    for (let col = 0; col <= 10; col++) {
        if (row == 0 && col == 0) {
            document.write('<td>x</td>');
        }
        else if (row == 0) {
            document.write('<td>' + col + '</td>');
        }
        else if (col == 0) {
            document.write('<td>' + row + '</td>');
        }
        else {
            document.write('<td>' + row * col + '</td>');
        }
    }
    document.write('</tr>');
}
```

Try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/s2budcrg/).